# how to select max and min

Tags: php, postgresql

I have script query select like this. I want to search value max and min 'jumlah' from query select.

```
SELECT 
     "B"."company" AS "B__company", 
     "User"."company" AS "User__company", 
     "Transaction"."create_date" AS "Transaction__create_date",
     extract(day from "Transaction"."create_date"),
     sum(cast("PLNPostpaid"."jumlahrek" as integer)) as jumlah,
     sum("Transaction"."price_buy") as jumbuy,
     sum(("Transaction"."price_sell")-("Transaction"."price_buy")) as admin


FROM "public"."transactions" AS "Transaction" 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."users" AS "User" ON ("User"."id" = "Transaction"."user_id") 
     FULL OUTER JOIN "public"."users" AS "B" ON ("B"."id" = "User"."bank") 
     LEFT JOIN "public"."inboxes" AS "Inbox" ON ("Inbox"."id" = "Transaction"."inbox_id")
     LEFT JOIN "public"."pln_postpaids" AS "PLNPostpaid" ON ("Inbox"."id" = "PLNPostpaid"."inbox_id")


WHERE "Transaction"."create_date" >= '01-May-2015 00:00:00' AND "Transaction"."create_date" <= '31-May-2015 23:59:59' 
      AND "Transaction"."product_id"=100


GROUP BY extract(day from "Transaction"."create_date"), "Transaction"."create_date", "B"."company", "User"."company"
```

and I want to implement to php. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I guess you have to use for sum you will get only one value. You will have to apply different query for this or use extra join in the same query for the required table.

Comment: @b0s3 no, not in postgresql.

Comment: @b0s3 The SQL standard syntax for quoting identifiers is `"identifier"` and this is supported by almost every database. Some databases still use legacy incompatible syntaxes like MySQL's backticks or MS-SQL's `[identifier]` quoting.

Comment: faizal, I can't really understand this. What exactly are you trying to do? What did you try already? In what way did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need a subquery to select min and max.
   For example,

WITH all_data AS (
       -- YOUR INITIAL REQUEST GOES HERE
    )
    SELECT MIN (jumlah) as min_jumlah, MAX(jumlah) as max_jumlah
    FROM all_data

2. It's unclear what syntax your code represents. If you compile the query from php, then you shouldn't use quotes like this. The whole string containing the query should be double quoted, but you don't need these double quotes inside.